# Erro ao tentar inicializar um projeto django clonado do github (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_filters')

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip, django-filter

Eu estou tentando rodar no meu pc um projeto django que clonei do github, porém se eu tento rodar o comando 'python manage.py' me retorna o seguinte erro:
  ***File "manage.py", line 16
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax***

e se eu tento executar o python3 manage.py runserver eu tenho o seguinte erro:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_filters'

Já tentei executar com e sem um ambiente virtual. Procurei saber e vi que talvez sejam versões diferentes do django instaladas. Caso seja isso, como eu posso fazer meu ambiente virtual rodar na versão correta, visto que não sei a versão que roda no ambiente original?

Comment: A princípio parece que o módulo *django-filter* não está instalado. Você já rodou `pip install -r requirements.txt`, `pip install django-filter` ou algo parecido?

Comment: Giovanni, o pip3 install django filter resolveu, eu estava tentando instalar o com o 's' que aparece no erro, no caso: pip3 install django-filters. mas agora está dando um outro erro... No module named 'psycopg2'. sabe qual comando pra instalar esse módulo?

Comment: Deve existir um arquivo chamado "requirements.txt" no projeto que você baixou e que contém as dependências dele para vocề instalá-las (no primeiro comentário está a sintaxe do `pip` para isto).

Comment: criei um requiriments.txt com o pip freeze que consegui do ambiente original e deu tudo certo, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Basta instalar as dependencias do projeto conforme os erros apresentados.

Verifique se no projeto há um arquivo chamado requirements.txt, caso não, instale as dependencias conforme os erros exibidos no console.

Para isntalar o django-filter, execute o comando pip install django-filter, para instalar o psycopg2, execute o comando pip install psycopg2-binary, e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Obrigado! eu apenas tinha que encontrar as versões corretas de algumas dependências.